# how to connect aws with my local system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have a project in the AWS as an AMI image and its an elasticsearch depended. I have an elasticsearch in my local system. Is there anyway to connect the AMI with the elasticsearch in my local system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify - are you asking how to connect your self-hosted/on-premise ElasticSearch to an AWS EC2 instance?

If so, you can create a VPN connection between your on-premise Network to your AWS VPC using strategies outlined in the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html)

You can also route the traffic via the Internet if you'd prefer - which depending on how your network looks may involve setting up some NAT port forwards.